# Python Mechanize response is empty

Tags: python-2.7, mechanize, mechanize-python

I need the response in order to make Python decide what to do next, but the response keeps being empty. What could be the problem?

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.open("https://www.facebook.com/login/identify?ctx=recover&lwv=110")
br.select_form(nr=1)
br.form["email"] = "test@gmail.com"
br.submit()
response = br.response().read()
print response
```

Thanks in advance!